# Issue with filter on Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Please help to understand. 
I have a django application with REST API. Everything working, but i wanna to add filter by client_id and here i received the issue.

There is a error message

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'B123456'
```

And sure this is my code

api.py

```
   class DatabaseByClientList(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        serializer_class = DatabaseSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            client_id = self.kwargs['client_id']
            return Database.objects.filter(client_id=client_id)
```

models.py

```
class Database(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['db_name']

    client_id = models.ForeignKey(ClientInfo)
    db_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    db_host = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    db_user = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    db_pass = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    db_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class DatabaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    client_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=ClientInfo.objects.all(),
                                           slug_field='access_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Database
        fields = ('id', 'client_id', 'db_name', 'db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_type')
```

What's wrong? I made everything like in off documentation.
Thanks,
PS I tried

```
return Database.objects.filter(client_id=client_id)
```

but it doesnt help also

Added ClientInfo class

```
class ClientInfo(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.access_id

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    access_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the `ClientInfo` class?

Comment: Self.kwargs ['client_id'], give you B123456? Because you need to pass and id to your filter. And this id, need to be an int. And int('B123456') raise this error.

Comment: There is no `name` field in your Model.  What do you mean by `filter by name`?

Comment: Added class ClientInfo

Comment: Python 3 I presume?

Comment: Yes, im using python3

Answer (score 0):

try to override get_queryset method this way.

```
class DatabaseByClientList(...):
    model = Database
    serializer_class = DatabaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(DatabaseByClientList, self).get_queryset()
        qs.filter(client_id=self.kwargs['client_id'])
        return qs
```

Comment: unfortunately in this case i receive error "
'DatabaseByClientList' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method."